# Mount a remote server with a proxy

Tags: ssh, remote-access, mount, sshfs

I'm trying to mount a remote directory From a server B on my local machine. 
The connection to server B is possible only from a server A ( I can connect to using ssh ).
It's like making the server A as a proxy for the server B.
So i'm asking if there is a way to do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Proxy Jump.
For that you can add server B in your local machine's ssh config file:

```
Host ServerB
    HostName serverb.adress
    User usernameInServerB
    ProxyJump server.a.adress
```

Then you can just use any usual ssh command on ServerB, for example:

```
 ssh ServerB
 or
 sshfs ServerB:Path/To/Dir
```

Comment: Thanks It works :) that's exactly what I was looking for .

Comment: Please close off-topic questions. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.